# How to iterate over children with the same name in an XML file using ptree(boost)?

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I have an XML file like this:

```
 <shape name="rightellipsoid" type="instance" id="eggBase">
    <transform name="xform1">
      <translate>2.5 1.5 -4.0</translate>
      <rotate axis="X">90.0</rotate>
      <scale>1.0 0.5 1.5</scale>
      <rotate axis="Y">95.0</rotate>
    </transform>
  </shape>
```

I'm able to retrieve the values of translate and scale using:

```
boost::optional<Vector3D> scale = v.second.get_optional<Vector3D>("scale");
```

Note: Vector3D is my data type

But if I do the same for my rotate node, it always returns me the first value.
How can I get the value of second rotation node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
std::string rotate_x, rotate_y;
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

BOOST_FOREACH( ptree::value_type const& val, pt.get_child("shape.transform") ) 
{
    if(val.first == "rotate") 
    {
        std::string temp = val.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.axis").data();

        if(temp == "X") rotate_x = val.second.data();
        if(temp == "Y") rotate_y = val.second.data();
    }
}
```